# Datagridview VB 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

i use a imagecolumn in a datagridview to display a png of 48 pixel. The image is selected based on the text of a button column in the same datagridview.

It's working fine, the only problem is that the first image don't change until i scrolldown and then scroll up again, after that all the image are show without problems until the first image again.

¿what can be the problem?.

here is the code i use for change the images.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting
If Not DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).IsNewRow Then
        If DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "Column4" Then
            'e.Value = Nothing
            If (DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value) = "NO Entregado" Then
                e.Value = Image.FromFile(procesando)
            ElseIf (DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value) = "Entregado" Then
                e.Value = Image.FromFile(lista)
            ElseIf (DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value) = "NO SE Entregará" Then
                e.Value = Image.FromFile(yellow)
            ElseIf (DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value) = "Devuelto" Then
                e.Value = Image.FromFile(green)
            End If
        End If
    End If
end sub
```

thanks in advance
sorry for the english.

Comment: Have you tried setting e.FormattingApplied to True?

Comment: No, i will try in the afternoon and comment what happen.

Comment: Not working, the same error, the first image is not changing, but the others after that are. i dont understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataGridView1.InvalidateColumn(3)` did the trick...